# Проверка паролей на совпадение jQuery при вводе

Tags: jquery, валидация

Пожалуйста помогите, никак разобраться не могу. Нужно на jQuery это всё сделать))

Есть форма состоящая из двух input:

**input[name="password"]** и **input[name="confirm_password"]**

И есть элементы с классами "length" и "match".

Нужно сделать так, что бы при вводе с клавиатуры делались проверки:

1) input[name="password"] >= 8 символов (если условие верно, то для "length" присвоить класс "done")

2) Два input'а равны между собой (если условие верно, то для "match" присвоить класс "done")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как простой пример можете сделать так:

```js
function  countCharPass(val){
var leng = val.value.length;
if(leng >= 8){
$('.length').addClass('done');
console.log('length done');
}else{
$('.length').removeClass('done');
console.log('length error');
}

if($('input[name="password"]').val().trim() === $('input[name="confirm_password"]').val().trim() ){
$('.match').addClass('done');
console.log('match done');
} else{
$('.match').removeClass('done');
console.log('match error');
}




}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="length"></p>
<p class="match"></p>



<input type="password" name="password" onkeyup="countCharPass(this)">
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" onkeyup="countCharPass(this)">
```